# error when trying to train with sklearn fit function

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm Practice AI with maths from https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mathurinache/math-dataset?resource=download, i have downloaded the dataset and i have made the next code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys
try:
    from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
    import json
    from time import sleep
except:
    os.system("pip install scikit-learn")
    os.system("pip install json")
    from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
    import json
    from time import sleep
# load paths
pathprincipal = rf'X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH'
pathprincipaltest = rf'X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\test'
pathprincipaltrain = rf'X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\train'
# paths for prediction and analyze the accuary of AI
pathtest1 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltest, "algebra")
pathtest2 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltest, "counting_and_probability")
pathtest3 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltest, "geometry")
pathtest4 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltest, "intermediate_algebra")
pathtest5 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltest, "number_theory")
pathtest6 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltest, "prealgebra")
pathtest7 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltest, "precalculus")
# paths for train the AI
pathtrain1 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltrain, "algebra")
pathtrain2 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltrain, "counting_and_probability")
pathtrain3 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltrain, "geometry")
pathtrain4 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltrain, "intermediate_algebra")
pathtrain5 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltrain, "number_theory")
pathtrain6 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltrain, "prealgebra")
pathtrain7 = os.path.join(pathprincipaltrain, "precalculus")
# trying load all train content
def parse_dataset(dataset_paths):
    X = []
    y = []
    for index, dataset in enumerate(dataset_paths): # index = 0, 1 ,2 etc , dataset = dirs inside train dir
        print("[+] Parsing {} data...".format(dataset))
        for fname in os.listdir(dataset): # fname = 0.json 1.json etc
            archivos = open(os.path.join(dataset, fname), 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').read() # opening the files 0.json, etc
            archivos2 = json.loads(archivos) # trying to read and load json files (0.json etc)
            X.append(archivos2) # append the .json contents in the list X
            y.append(index) # append the numbers 0, 1 , 2 etc in list y
            
    return(X, y)

X, y = parse_dataset([pathtrain1, pathtrain2, pathtrain3,pathtrain4,pathtrain5,pathtrain6,pathtrain7])
# same than def parse_dataset1 the difference here is test dir and subdirs content
def parse_dataset2(dataset_paths):
    X2 = []
    y2 = []
    for index, dataset in enumerate(dataset_paths):
        print("[+] Parsing {} data...".format(dataset))
        for fname in os.listdir(dataset):
            archivos = open(os.path.join(dataset, fname), 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').read()
            archivos2 = json.loads(archivos)
            X2.append(archivos2)
            y2.append(index)
            
    return(X2, y2)
X2, y2 = parse_dataset([pathtest1, pathtest2, pathtest3,pathtest4,pathtest5,pathtest6,pathtest7])
# trying to train algorithm
clf = MLPClassifier(activation='logistic', hidden_layer_sizes=(10,), solver='sgd')
clf.fit(X,y)
# trying to predict
prediccion = clf.predict(X2)
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
f1_score(X2, y2, average="binary")
```

but my problem is when i run my code i get this error

```
X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi>python Math_Predict.py
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\train\algebra data...
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\train\counting_and_probability data...
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\train\geometry data...
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\train\intermediate_algebra data...
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\train\number_theory data...
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\train\prealgebra data...
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\train\precalculus data...
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\test\algebra data...
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\test\counting_and_probability data...
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\test\geometry data...
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\test\intermediate_algebra data...
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\test\number_theory data...
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\test\prealgebra data...
[+] Parsing X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\MATH\test\precalculus data...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi\Math_Predict.py", line 74, in <module>
    clf.fit(X,y)
  File "C:\Users\XGreen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py", line 747, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, incremental=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XGreen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py", line 437, in _fit
    X, y = self._validate_input(X, y, incremental, reset=first_pass)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XGreen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py", line 1087, in _validate_input
    X, y = self._validate_data(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XGreen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 565, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XGreen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 1106, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XGreen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 879, in check_array
    array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XGreen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_array_api.py", line 185, in _asarray_with_order
    array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'dict'

X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\inteligencia artificial\scripts IA por mi>python Math_Predict.py
```

what i'm doing wrong and how i can fix it?, i have tried to add .fit_transform but didnt worked, it give me different error, so i dont know how to fix this , i hope someone can help me, thanks :)

Comment: `archivos2 = json.loads(archivos)` creates a `dict`.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: i'm trying to add the text of json inside a list for train the AI, in resume i'm trying to load the data and add it in a list for train it

Comment: An example file (`Math/train/number_theory/1007.json`) contains `"root": {"problem": "What is the base-ten number represented by the base-eight number 31?", "level": "Level 2", "type": "Number Theory",  "solution": "$31_8=3\\cdot8^1+1\\cdot8^0=\\boxed{25}$."}`  What text do you want to add to `X`?

Comment: bassically i have two dir, dir test , dir train, i want add all the content of dir train (all files.json) inside X, and i want add all content of dir test on X2

Comment: `archivos` will have all the text, yes?

Comment: yes, the "def parse_dataset" contain all data for train the AI, the "def parse_dataset2" contain all data for test the prediction of AI

Comment: archivos open all files, archivos2 loads all content from files

Comment: `archivos2` interprets `archivos` as JSON and produces a `dict`.

Comment: well in resume i want bassically load all data and train the AI hehe, i dont know how to fix it

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your model, nor what you are trying to train.

Comment: The dataset have 2 dir, dir Train, and Dir Test, in the Def Function "def parse_dataset" i'm trying to train all dirs and all json inside dirs in Train dir, the "Def Function "def parse_dataset2" is the same than the first, the difference is this function is for all the dataset of "test" dir, but in where i'm trying to train is in the function def parse_dataset (load all .json files inside a list) later trying to train and predict with clf.fit and clf.predict

Comment: You are trying to train a model that can predict a file index based on the text of the file?

Comment: i have docummented the code, (edited the post for you understand it better, my goal is train the AI with the def parse_dataset function for later be abble to predict with the def parse_dataset2 function

Comment: There error is caused by `X` having `dict`s for `MLPClassifier.fit(X,y)`. `archivos2 = json.loads(archivos)` creates a `dict`.  If you have another/more questions about implementing your model, perhaps another question would be more appropriate.

Comment: hi rick , so then for fix this what i can do for archivos2 = json.loads(archivos) dont load the data in dict mode?

Comment: I believe `MLPClassifier` requires numeric input data.  I don't know how you want to transform your data to numeric format.

Comment: so then i guess the dataset is bad?

Comment: TBH, I think the dataset is fine - your model seems inadequate for the dataset.

Comment: what type of model do you recommend me?

Comment: Based on what input, what do you want to model/predict?  If you are just starting with machine learning, maybe [Kaggle's _"Titanic - Machine Learning from Disaster"_](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic) would be a good place to start.

Comment: The [_"Titanic Tutorial"_](https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexisbcook/titanic-tutorial/notebook) looks pretty good too.

Comment: hi rick, thank you im going to check :)